# Bootstrap tooltip arrow broken from second number of tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment, tooltip

I want to make 4 tooltips like the image below. I am using bootstrap 3 and everything is just default, I didn't change anything to modify this. Just my text is different in color, that's it, tooltips are default.
[image]

You can see it's appearing perfectly on the first tooltip, but on the third one the arrow is broken slightly. The second one and fourth one are also broken from arrow only.

I want all of them to appear perfectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please put in fiddle for us to check*

*edited my answer based on the comments.

As the fiddle is working with no css, i would guess that there is a confliction with maybe a custome.css file that you made for the site.

Its possible that a class that Bootstrap has given the tooltip in bootstrap.css may conflict against a class you have made for something else in your html to add css to it with your custome.css file.

If that makes sense? :-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soeb/rdxu9upp/
In jsfiddle it's working fine. I think there is something with my other stylesheets.

Comment: Its possible that one is casuing issues to the other.

Comment: Bootstrap designed the tooltip, so assuming there is no CSS in that fiddle, you might find that something in your custom CSS file relates to that Class?

Comment: I didn't written anything on bootstrap default tooltip classes i have just applied them in html that's all.
Still let me check thoroughly.

Comment: What I mean is, bootstrap may assign a class called "tooltip" for instance, and in you custom CSS file, you may also have called something "tooltip"